# A method to list all files in directory and sub-directories using boost and c++

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I have the following code to search all files in a directory and all its sub-directories. the code uses recursion for nested sub-directories.

```
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

void getDirectoryFiles(path p, vector<string> &files) {
    if (exists(p)) {
        if (is_regular_file(p)) {
            files.push_back(p.string());
            return;
        }
        else if (is_directory(p)) {
            for (directory_entry& x : directory_iterator(p)) {
                getDirectoryFiles(x.path(), files);
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "exists, but not a file of a directory!\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Path not exists!";
        return;
    }
};
```

The general idea taken from [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html#Directory-iteration) with a twist.
Any one to optimize this code?

Comment: Questions asking for improvement of working code should go to [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please move there.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know a `directory_iterator` could be used as a range itself. Handy. `istream_iterator` should have this feature.

Answer (score 2):

There is a recursive_directory_iterator for that.

Making a sample:

```
fs::path dir = ".";
fs::recursive_directory_iterator it(dir), end;

std::vector<std::string> files;
for (auto& entry : boost::make_iterator_range(it, end))
    if (is_regular(entry))
        files.push_back(entry.path().native());
```